# Intel Turbo overheats my CPU

Tags: laptop, cpu, temperature, cpu-temperature

I have a MSI GF75 Thin 10SCSR laptop with Intel Core I7 10750H CPU. When turbo is on, each core's FID increases up to 45 and CPU temperature reaches 85-90C while gaming. But while turbo is off, FID is limited to 26 and CPU reaches 45-50C while gaming (same game, same load). Is it normal? (temp and function of turbo) Can I turn turbo on but limit it to lower frequencies?
Note : I turned turbo off using ThrottleStop.

Comment: You have a mobile processor so it indeed will run hotter than a desktop processor due to the differences in the ability to cool it.  Unless the processor is throttling itself and/or the system is turning off then your processor isn't actually overheating. While powerful your processor might not be up to the task, by turning of ThrottleStop you are limiting your processor potential performance.

Comment: @Ramhound so you mean 80-90 degrees is ok?

Comment: @IliaAlizadeh T-JUNCTION (maximum allowed temperature at CPU die) is 100°C for this cpu:  https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/201837/intel-core-i7-10750h-processor-12m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz.html

Comment: I am simply saying that your CPU is not overheating unless your machine is shutting itself down automatically and/or it's being thermally throttled.  You don't mention any specific performance problems from the CPU being at that temperature.  The only performance problem you could have is disabling your CPU's ability to boost itself to a higher frequency.